# How Do I Migrate My FDT 5.5 License To Another Machine / I've Run Out Of Activations?

Tags: licensing, fdt

I have FDT Max and I've just upgraded my machine.  I want to un-install FDT from one computer and install onto another.  When I installed FDT on the new computer I'm informed that my license has expired.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of seeing a license:

1. Your license as a subscription. In this case, you have a reoccurring FDT license (subscription) which grants you the ability to authorize on two machines.
2. Your license as two activations. This is usually the case when the standalone is purchased. You can activate it on two machines.

If you have a subscription license and you wish to discontinue it, [go here](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/subscription-interface) to stop it.

If you have have either a subscription or one time purchase license and have run out of activations (e.g. 2 machines have already been activated), you need to deactivate it via FDT itself (see screenshots below).

If this doesn't work for you, e.g. you've already thrown out your old computer, then [contact sales](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/contact/) and they will work with you to reset your activations.

[image]
[image]